# Running a loop in background in android

Tags: android

I am not very comfortable with android. I I tried making a simple alarm.I tried running a thread and running a loop inside it for a match with the current time. But apparently I am not good at multi threading either in android. So can anyone give a code snippet as example how do I run a loop inside a thread and when the time passes, shows a toast.

Comment: Better give us what you did first (your code)

Comment: Android: " :'( You will be comfortable when you will try to understand me </3"

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1.) Create a service ,.
2.) Through this service start a thread.
3.) In run method of thread , create your logic to compare time and put this code in

while(true)
        {

```
     //Your code logic

    }
```

P.S. Dont forget to register your service in manifest.
P.P.S. This will consume a lot of battery .Why dont you try with AlarmManager .